# When should I create a view controller programmatically, and when should I use a NIB file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am trying to programmatically create a view controller. I would like to know when I should create the view controller using a NIB file, and when I should create it programmatically.

I would also like step-by-step instructions to create the view controller without a NIB file.

Comment: This is almost entirely nonsensical; can you try to rephrase it more clearly?

Comment: please see here         this is for  IB. i need without IB .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257740/viewcontroller-all-function-call-hierarchy-in-iphone-from-nib-and-when-should-i-u/5257940#5257940

Comment: Sounds like someone is using some terrible english translation software...

Comment: Your post is best example of word salad I've yet seen on stackoverflow. You're going to have to make sense if you want any answers.

Comment: I think he's working through a web translator. We'll have to do some puzzling out from our end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to use IB for ViewControllers that contain mostly static views. When a ViewController has a lot of views that I need to create dynamically, or animate I prefer to create the ViewController with code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270241/complete-list-of-lifecycle-functions-of-viewcontroller-from-starting-to-end-of-th could u please explain about this question.while i create the viewcontroller in IB the awakefromnib did not called.i want the seperate  list for lifecycle of viewcontroller while creating with IB and with manual code.please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Use the IB when ever you like to. Use code in the remaining cases.

Here is how you can get rid of the IB in the creation of the AppDelegate.

1. Remove the entry "Main nib file base name" in the Info.plist
2. Change `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` in main.m to `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyCoolApplicationAppDelegate");` where "MyCoolApplication" is the name of your app.
3. Add in "MyCoolApplicationAppDelegate" in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:application` the following code:

   window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

To create a view controller without a nib do:

```
MyCoolViewController *myCoolViewController = [[MyCoolViewController alloc] init];
```

and in the load view of MyCoolViewController you can add initialize the corresponding view and attach it to the your view controller via:

```
[self setView: MyCoolView];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS: Understanding the View Management Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW19).

That should tell you when and why the methods are called and in what order.