# Complete list of Lifecycle functions of ViewController from Starting To End of that Life without using the NIB and With using NIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want complete list of lifecycle functions of view controller with correct sequence.Please any genius.

Please **specify with Exact sequence number** and **From** ***start to End*** of **ViewController's LifeCycle Functions**.

Please specify with sequence Number like with **usage:** and with only **short description.** 
example:

### **with** using NIB

1.alloc

usage:blah..blah..

2..init

usage:blah..blah..

3...viewdidload

usage:blah..blah..

### **without** using NIB

1.alloc

usage:blah..blah..

2..init

usage:blah..blah..

3...viewdidload

usage:blah..blah..

..

..

..

Everyone listen please, we have to first understand this concept to make easy as a iPhone Developer.

Once we understand all of them correctly then we can make anything easier.

**I have searched for this Google but i can't get the right answer.**

because **everyone said different according to their understanding** and this make me so **confusing more**.

Answer (score 5):

To figure out in what order they are called you could use the debugger and a couple of breakpoints or simply put a `NSLog(@"viewDidLoad was called");` call in each method.

Experienced programmers would use `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);` because it automatically prints the method name and can be copied&pasted faster.

The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html) can be handy too. It explains all that in detail.

Comment: i Knew about nslog stuff.but i want to know sequence of methods should i follow to using NIB and Without using NIB

Comment: To be honest: I wonder how fluchtpunkt was able to answer your (rather, IMHO) inpolite question so politely. Maybe you should think about thanking him/her? As always: reading the documentation helps a lot ;)