# Annotations and Table Views

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I am trying populate my table view using my array of annotations but XCode seems to give me a breakpoint any time I add this code.

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    for(Location *annotation in [(MKMapView *)self annotations])
    {
        if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
    }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
}
return cell;
```

My annotations:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D thecoordinate59;

thecoordinate59.latitude = 51.520504;
thecoordinate59.longitude = -0.106725; 
Location *ann1 = [[Location alloc] init];
ann1.title =@"Antwerp";
ann1.coordinate = thecoordinate1;

NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray arraywithObjects: ann.. ann59, nil];

[map addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Comment: Post the whole `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method here. This is kinda messy.

Comment: breakpoint on the for(Location *annotation in [(MKMapview *)self annotations

Comment: What error does the console say you have? (a breakpoint isn't an error).

Comment: Show how the annotations array is declared and initialized in your detail view.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina i have 59 annotation

Answer (score 2):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you are declaring a new, local variable named `annotations` which has nothing to do with the `annotations` array you are creating in `viewDidLoad` (I assume that's where you're adding the annotations).

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this line:

```
for(Location *annotation in [(MKMapView *)self annotations])
```

fails because there is no `annotations` property in `self`.  In `viewDidLoad`, you declared a local variable named `annotations` but it is not visible or accessible outside that method.

The other issue with the above line is that you're casting `self` as an `MKMapView *`.  Most likely `self` is a `UIViewController`.  It contains a map view but is not itself one.

You need to first declare your `annotations` array at the detail view's class level so it's available across all methods.  In the detail view .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *annotations;
```

By the way, I'd name it something different so it's not confused with the map view's own `annotations` property.

In the .m, synthesize it:

```
@synthesize annotations;
```

In `viewDidLoad`, create it like this:

```
self.annotations = [NSMutableArray arraywithObjects...
[map addAnnotations:self.annotations];
```

In the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, return the array's count:

```
return self.annotations.count;
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: Are the map and table in the same view controller?  In another comment you mention a detail view.  What's the "masterviewcontroller" and what's the "detail view"?

Comment: the error i receive 
Property 'annotations' not found on object of type 'MasterViewController*'
any time i use self.annotations

Comment: Am using splitview for iPad. The table view is for the masterviewcontroller and detailview for the map

Comment: First, in the viewDidLoad of the masterviewcontroller, put this NSLog and let me know what it says: `NSLog(@"dvc = %@", [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]);`

Comment: dvc = <UINavigationController: 0x76222b0

Comment: Next: In masterviewcontroller, do you already have a reference to the detailviewcontroller and are you using it?

Comment: if i populate the table manually with the same string names is there anyway to connect them using the string names.

Comment: No, the basic idea is this: The two view controllers need to share data.  My suggestion would be to let the masterviewcontroller create and manage the annotations array and have the detailviewcontroller ask the masterviewcontroller for the data.  Other possibilities (which I don't recommend) are to put the data in a singleton object or to put the array in the app delegate.

Comment: I recommend this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031238/uisplitviewcontroller-master-detail-communication

Answer (score 0):

You are reporting a crash (i assume) on that line

the problem that I see is crash reason would be

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

`annotations` array is just initialized locally few statements above which does not hold any values..??

Comment: i have an array of annotation with the declaration NSMutableArray *annotations in my detail view.

Comment: so how can u say that here that your local variable `annotations` is not being considered here in code rather than the one which you are mentioning?

Comment: i cannot populate the map annotations on the table view.

Comment: I dont get what you are saying