# Store text and retrieve in the next view

Tags: ios, xcode, file, view, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in the first view, I have to store the text and retrieve onto the next view. Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into delegates.  It allows one view to provide a callback to another view without creating tight coupling.

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/

[What exactly does delegate do in xcode ios project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215698/what-exactly-does-delegate-do-in-xcode-project/7215969#7215969)

Another option is to create a shared model (read up on model view controller patterns). It's typical in that pattern to create a model and share data by getting a singleton instance of your model:

```
MyModel *model = [MyModel sharedInstance];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the data  and  you can retrieve in any class

To Store:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:userName.text forKey:@"userNameKey"];
```

To retrieve:

```
       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

       NSString *userName = [prefs stringForKey:@"userNameKey"];
```