# Determining which UIView was navigated from

Tags: iphone, uiview, navigationcontroller

I have a view that is on the navigation stack.  From this view a user can navigate to a few different views.  When navigating back to this view from one of those various views, I need to know which view the user came from.

**Example:**
User goes from HomeView to View1 using navigation controller.  When navigating back to HomeView, how can I determine that they are coming from View1?  I thought of using a global variable, but that seems hokey.

Thank you.

Comment: go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118598/what-is-the-difference-between-notifications-delegates-and-protocols

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.Same question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate or Notification.