# Delegate multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have main view controller which has connection to 2 view controller's.
I made protocol where I have didRecive(data:Data) delegate function.

```
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate: class {
func didReciveDepartment(response:DepartmentResponse)
```

}

In main view controller I declare delegate var.

```
    weak var delegate: DepartmentMainViewControllerDelegate?
```

In prepare for segue I set this delegate to viewCotnroller's. Like so -

```
        if segue.identifier == "productsEmbedded" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentProductsViewController
        delegate = vc


    }
    if segue.identifier == "shopsEmbedded" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentShopsViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        delegate = vc
    }
```

I have wired behavior delegate only triggers in DepartmentShopsViewController, and DepartmentProductsViewController can't get this delegate, I commented out shops and products got this delgate so it means I can't use same delegate for 2 controllers?

Comment: you want to have a separate variable....How can you save two objects in same variable

Comment: Just made second delegate var and didn't worked.

Comment: what is ` delegate = vc` in `productsEmbedded` segue?

Comment: you also have to call the second delegate...

Comment: Where you have created the protocol? and which controller setting the delegate?

Comment: you can also use noficationcenter for this purpose.

Comment: I updated question where I show how I make protocol

Comment: @Prabhat notification is last thing which I want use, I want to try to solve this challenge using delegates.

Comment: You want send data from  main view controller to 2 view controller??

Comment: @luckyShubhra Yes and trigger delegate to refresh tableview's in those 2 viewcotnroller's

Answer (score 2):

These are many ways to pass messages between objects. You can pass data using Delegate and using NSNotificationCentre. The main difference is with delegates, one designated object receives a message, wheras 
any number of objects can receive notifications when they are posted.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118598/what-is-the-difference-between-notifications-delegates-and-protocols) previous SO ques for details.

Comment: Wrong, those 2 view controllers connected to main as container's, and I use preapreForSegue only one time, when MainViewController is inited. There I setting those delegates, and delegates from those viewcontroller's to main controller to establishes communication between them.

Comment: Clarify me how you get data in your MainViewController ??

Comment: I pass it through preapreForSegue from previous controller which present MainViewController, and later one I just update this data from function inside MainViewController.

Comment: can you show me where you have defined protocol DepartmentMainViewControllerDelegate ??

Comment: check question I just removed Department letter. It's defined in DepartmentMainViewController class.

Comment: Btw if u need to update data from one view controller to 2 view controller. Its not feasible. Delegate is for one to one connection. For one to many NSNotificationCentre should be used.

Comment: I want avoid NotificaitonCenter, what also I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Come on man you forgotten a line

```
    vc.delegate = self
```

The code should look like this

```
if segue.identifier == "productsEmbedded" {
    let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentProductsViewController
    vc.delegate = self     //Add this Line   
    delegate = vc
}
if segue.identifier == "shopsEmbedded" {
    let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentShopsViewController
    vc.delegate = self
    delegate = vc
}
```

Comment: Wrong, check question I have all this thing's delegate triggers in one controller. and vc.delgate on DepartmentsShops because I have DepartmentShopsDelegatei it's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

For Delegate you have to implement like that

```
//Declare protocol
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate {
    func didReciveDepartment(response:DepartmentResponse)
}

class DepartmentProductsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variable Declaration.
    var delegate: MainViewControllerDelegate?

}

class DepartmentShopsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Variable Declaration.
    var delegate: MainViewControllerDelegate?

}

class  MainViewController: UIViewController, MainViewControllerDelegate {

    //Push ViewController with segue and  use delegate property
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "productsEmbedded"{

            let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentProductsViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier == "shopsEmbedded" {

            let vc = segue.destination as! DepartmentShopsViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }

    //MARK: Implement MainViewControllerDelegate Methods.
    func didReciveDepartment(response: DepartmentResponse) {

    }

}
```